# serialize form data saved in elmah log into model object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding, elmah

I have Elmah logging errors. Errors save full form post information. I can access these errors and their XML or JSON representation by URL. Some of the errors that I'd like to debug have a lot of values posted and reproducing these errors is very hard and time consuming.

What I'd like, is a method that would populate model that is required for a particular post action using elmah log information. Then I could use this model in a unit test and see exactly why error occurs.

So far I've tried parsing into model from XML and JSON elamh error information. Below is what I tried parsing from JSON:

```cs
MyModel model = ParseTo<MyModel>("Url of elmah json error");
```

```cs
public static T ParseTo<T>(string UrlOfJson)
{
    string fullJsonString = string.Empty;
    using(var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        fullJsonString = webClient.DownloadString(UrlOfJson);
    }

    JObject o = JObject.Parse(fullJsonString);
    string inputString = o.SelectToken("form").ToString();

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(inputString);
}
```

This almost works. Almost because it cannot deserialize List objects.

Given the following model:

```cs
public class MyModel
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public List<Offer> Offers { get; set; }
}

public class Offer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

... and this Json:

```
{
    "CustomerId": "4564",
    "Offers[0].Id": "635",
    "Offers[0].Name": "name1",
    "Offers[1].Id": "636",
    "Offers[1].Name": "name2",
}
```

... the parser fails to serialize `Offers` property because Json saved by Elmah is not in the correct format for that. It's in the format that would be understood by default ModelBinder, but how can I run it against this Json?

Any ideas how I can serialize Json saved by Elamh into a model object?

Comment: But... you actually stored FormCollection key-value pairs in the log. Not Model itself. Right?

Comment: I didn't store any data myself. Elmah logs form post info out of the box when an error is thrown. The form post info essentially is a model information.

Answer (score 1):

Full working example in default MVC4 HomeController:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace DefaultMvc4Application.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public class MyModel
        {
            public int CustomerId { get; set; }
            public List<Offer> Offers { get; set; }
        }

        public class Offer
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            string json = @"{
                                ""CustomerId"": ""4564"",
                                ""Offers[0].Id"": ""635"",
                                ""Offers[0].Name"": ""name1"",
                                ""Offers[1].Id"": ""636"",
                                ""Offers[1].Name"": ""name2"",
                            }";
            var dict = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
            var form = new FormCollection();

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dict)
                form.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);


            var model = new MyModel();
            UpdateModel<MyModel>(model, form);

            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

At the end you get properly populated model.

Comment: This is great! I appreciate help. The only problem now is that method `UpdateModel` is not available in any class that does not inherit from `Controller`. Therefore I cannot use it in Test. I've searched all over the place how to convert `FormCollection` to a Poco, but could not find anything useful

Comment: UpdateModel is dependent on MVC infrastructure (IModelBinder, ControllerContext, HttpContext, etc...). You would need to mock to many things for "UnitTest". Then, if there was any custom configuration (custom model binder, etc...) you would not be able to reproduce the problem accurately (if at all).
Basically, you want to reproduce end-to-end failure withing isolated UnitTest, which is, by definition, wrong.
(Not to mention using of webClient to load "unit-test" data)

Comment: Luckily for me there is no custom configuration in my site. Streight forward default settings including model binder. Just too many inputs on the form. I don't care about definitions. I just want to solve a problem.

Comment: Fair enough. But using those definitions wrongly, you might confuse readers of your question above. Anyway, then you have to use mocking framework to make it work without Http run-time.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified example:

```
    FormCollection form = ParseTo<FormCollection>("Url of elmah json error");
    var instance = new MyModel();
    UpdateModel<MyModel>(instance, form.ToValueProvider());
```

So, basically, only deserialize JSON to `System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection` first. Or in `NameValueCollection`, then you can create `FormCollection` from there. Then, trigger MVC binding and you will get your model.

This snippet should be inside of controller action, so that you have access to `Controller.UpdateModel` method (or `TryUpdateModel`).

Comment: I can't have code in Controller. I need it in a TestClass for the reasons described in the question. Also, as you can see in the question, the TODO part that you left off is the part I struggle the most with.

Comment: Yuo got it completely wrong. You have to simply replace deserialization target class. And since it's MVC model binding format, not JSON you HAVE to use MVC model binding to create object. At the end... try it first in controller, make it work, and then play with your test class.

Comment: you lost me. It would be great if you could provide more code. Specifically the code that could be written in Test Class. Though I understand that I ask a lot.

Comment: Yes, you have to do something yourself. I changed 1st line of code, to make it even more obvious for you. You have all elements you need to deserialize MyModel. Rest you can really do on your own.